# How to insert new rows if they don't exist and delete if they do exist?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an array of data which comes from user input (select dropdown). The dropdown has some default values and user can select more or deselect the default ones(database data). After submitting, I want to check if they are in db and the user has deselect from dropdown, or if user has  selected more and insert those ones.

```
$sql_insert_update_locations = $dbi->prepare("INSERT INTO my_items_table (user_id,location_id) VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id=VALUES(user_id), location_id=VALUES(location_id)");

 foreach ($location_id as $loc_id) {
    $sql_insert_update_locations->bind_param("ii", $user_id, $loc_id);
    $sql_insert_update_locations->execute();
 }
```

the query above inserts/updates the newly selected but doesn't check if anything has been deselected to delete them from db.

Comment: Not worth an answer, but I'd create a new array by selecting the DB rows prior to the update, use `array_diff()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php to find items in that array that don't exist in new selection, and write your delete query to iterate over from the resulting array

Comment: @TCooper so basically write two queries, one to insert/update and one to delete, right?

Comment: I'm not aware of any rdbms out there that would combine insert / update / delete into a single sql statement, so you need another query to delete records.

Comment: Although it's your code and you can do what you want, variable names like `$sql_insert_update_locations` are really far too verbose and cutter up your code considerably, making it a lot harder to read. Something like `$stmt` is more conventional.

Comment: @Shadow . . . Actually, I would say that more databases than not support `merge`, which does exactly what the OP is asking for.  MySQL is not one of those databases, though.